# Sum of arithmetic sequence plus m (Sn + m)

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Let $a_n=n$, $a_m=m$. $n\ne m.$ Find $S_{n+m}$.

Should I implement the $S_{n}$ formula and then add m?

[1]: Source :https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZK0Z.png

Comment: If you have a formula for $S_n$, just plug $n+m$ into the formula. Note that you've copied down the problem differently from how it is in the picture. It may help if you could provide more context for this problem.

Comment: Oops,I corrected it and added formula,but not $S_{n+m}$ @TomKern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $S_n$ as a function $S(n)$ that, given a natural number $n$, computes the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to $n$, i.e. $S(n) = 1 + 2 + ... + n$. Note that this is an *arithmetic series* with $a_1=1, d=1$, so
$$S_n = S(n) = \frac{n(2 + (n-1))}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, \quad \text{(you can also prove it by induction)}$$
Now, you are asked to find $S_{n+m}$. If you think of $S_n$ as a function that takes integers as input values, then what you need to do is to *evaluate* $S(n)$ at the point $n+m$:
$$S_{n+m} = S(n+m) = \frac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}{2}.$$